# Javascript: input box - autocapitalize first letter but can override

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, capitalize

I have a name input box. I would like to auto-capitalise the first letter of the name as the user types, but allow the user to override the change for names such as "de Salis".

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046284/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-an-input) that this is impossible with CSS, because `text-transform:capitalize;` will capitalise every word and can't be overridden.

A `.keyup` handler can fix up the first letter as you type, and there are a bunch of solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017456/with-jquery-how-do-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-text-field-while-the-user) to do that.

What I can't see how the original capitalisation can be overriden easily. I guess I need a flag, but if the function is one that can be attached to multiple elements, where should the flag live? I could append a DOM element as a flag, but this seems pretty ugly.

A fiddle of the non-override model is found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tpgHx/).

Suggestions?

Comment: maybe try the .one() http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Yep, beautiful @jSweazy. I've created an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/szhxd/1/  Write it up as an answer and I'll tick it :)

Comment: Thanks. I was waiting to see if you respond :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the input box show only the ***first capital letter***, you can use the `keyCode` directly, as that is always in ***uppercase*** format.

That alone will alleviate the requirement for expensive `regex` and `.replace()` methods your using.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.auto').one('keyup', function(e) {
    $(this).val(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
});
```

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M4vS8/)

---

The following answer has been revised to include `Tab Key` requirements, clicking inside of input box and pasting via context-menu, using keyboard paste method (Ctrl + V), and directly typing into it. It does away with the character `keyCodes` so ***international support*** is acknowledged. The jQuery selector was obtained [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7106392/1195891).

**RE-Revised:** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XfaPn/1/) (*Does not force capital letter on submit.*)

Comment: A slight hitch. If you `tab` into the input box, it fires the function and shoots the cursor across. The other approach is also triggered when you tab in, but it only becomes obvious with the `keyCode` approach because the other way doesn't move the cursor. I'll have to work around this :)

Comment: See **Status Update** for new jsFiddle. Cheers!

Comment: What about my French AZERTY keyboard? When I type an `é` I get a `2` ! ;)

Comment: @Cyrille, I believe my latest jsFiddle should work with international keyboards now. Cheers!

Comment: I've accepted following jSweazy's comment above. I suspect, however, that including input in the handler means that it will always revert to a capital when you submit your result. I haven't got time to test it now, though :)

Comment: Re-revised jsFiddle via removing the `change` selector that was causing submit issue. :-D

Comment: Nice work. Another quick question: `.one('input keypress', function...` does the job for my purposes, but `.one('keypress', function...` doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Here's more info on [**jQuery .keypress();**](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) and for `input` review the reference in my answer for where I obtained that entire selector. Cheers!