# In html text-transform property not working with initial in the text box

Tags: html, css

In my HTML page I set the style of my text box as `initial` for `text-transform` property, But not working with `initial`. I also test with other values like `uppercase`, `lowercase`, `capitalize` works fine but with `initial` no change. I want when user enter text into the text box text should input with first letter capital and remaining as he/she entered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-transform: initial;

}

:-moz-placeholder { 
   text-transform: initial;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  
   text-transform: initial;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { 
   text-transform: initial;
}
input{
   text-transform: initial;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" placeholder="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Also tried

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
input:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type='text' >

</body>
</html>
```

No luck.

Comment: For first letter capital you need to capitalize. Your question is contradicting .. What do you actually want?

Comment: As example ,I enter  "i am alfiza" it should be like "I am alfiza" not "I Am Alfiza".that's why I cant use capitalize.

Comment: You can set first letter as uppercase. see below examples.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5577380/6742472

Comment: first-letter does not work on input elements @Nilam

Comment: What do you expect `initial` to do? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial.

Comment: When user enter any text first letter should be capital remaining as it is. I noticed it works in <p> <span> etc but not for input element why its like that.

Comment: That's not what `initial` means. Read the documentation referred to in earlier comment. There is no CSS property for capitalizing only the first word of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this inside a function:
For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('input').on('keypress', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val();
        val = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1);
        $this.val(val);
   });
});
```

This will give you the desired output. Hope this helps :)

Comment: when this function will called? on key down ?

Comment: Yes you can call on key down or on key press.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keydown(function(){
        var val = $('input').val();
        val = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1);
        $('input').val(val);
    });
});

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be under the impression that `text-transform: initial` means "initial caps", or "capitalize only the very first letter". That's not what `initial` means. `initial` is a CSS-wide keyword that means "the initial value of this property". It has no relation to `text-transform` whatsoever.

The initial value of `text-transform` is `none`. So `text-transform: initial` has the same effect as `text-transform: none`.

There is no value of `text-transform` that means "initial caps". Normally for non-replaced elements you would [apply the text transform to `::first-letter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577364/make-the-first-character-uppercase-in-css/5577380#5577380), but since you're dealing with an `input` element here I'm not sure there's a solution in pure CSS.

Besides, applying text transforms to a form field is a terrible idea in the first place, especially if the field is case-sensitive. If I were you, I wouldn't do it at all.

Comment: Agree with your answer.But what can be the solution for it please any idea. i also tried the first-letter but not works for input.

Comment: Don't you feel there should be a property that can do the same?

Comment: @Alfiza malek: If you agreed with my answer, you wouldn't be asking those questions, since you should have seen my pre-emptive answers to them. The fact that you're still asking shows that you haven't accepted and therefore don't agree with what I said. Sure I feel there should be a value for text-transform that allows this, but too bad - there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

This would be the css

```
 input{
          text-transform: capitalize;
    }
```

Comment: It will convert my all the words with first letter capital .i don't want that.i want only first letter of the line capital.

Comment: @Alfizamalek There is no such CSS property.

Comment: in js ,see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046284/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-an-input